# Add and Remove selected value of one combobox to another combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsp

I need to select the value from combobox1 and then selected values are printed in another combobox2 after click the add button... If i want to remove value from combobox2 that selected  value removed from combobox2.. Any one help me to do this.. we have any seperate JQuery for that... Thanks in advance..

Comment: Can you please add the code here?

Comment: i already add one combobox value to another by using this link http://jsfiddle.net/EHqem/  ... Now i need to remove

Answer (score 2):

Here is the logic, **cb1** is id combobox1 and **cb2** is id for combobox2 and **add** is id for add button

```
 $("#add").unbind().bind("click", function(){<br/>
 var val = $("#cb1").find('option:selected').html();<br/>
 $("#cb1").find('option:selected').remove();<br/>
 var option = $('<option>').appendTo('#cb2');<br/>
 $('#cb2 ').find('option:last').val(val);<br/>
 $('#cb2 ').find('option:last').text(val);<br/>

 });
```

Comment: no you don't. Your browser is smartest in whole world. off-course man